# Oracle taking too long to return invaild username/password error

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection

We have a scenario where its taking around 10 seconds to get the application takes about 10 seconds to get the SQL Exception (stating logon denied as the userid/password combination is invalid) from the Application Server.

I wrote a small java app just to directly initiate the sql connection.

public class TestUsingJ2SE {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Date start = new Date();

    Connection conn = null;

    Date end = new Date();

    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", "ivr_cds");
    connectionProps.put("password", "something");

    start = new Date();

    try {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
        DriverManager.getDriver(url);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connectionProps);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Driver Manager --> error ..." + e.getMessage());
    }

    end = new Date();

    System.out.println("Using Driver Manager ..");
    System.out.println("Started at:" + start + " and finished at:" + end);
    System.out.println("Duration :" + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));

}
```

}

We found out that it still takes 10 seconds for oracle to come back with a invalid/username password error. The jar I had used for connecting to oracle was ojdbc5.jar (JAVA 5 version) as our env is on WAS 6.1.2.

When I used ojdbc6.jar(JAVA 6 version) and ran the above program oracle came back with invalid username/password in 600ms.

Any clues as why this would be happening and if there is some parameter in Oracle which could be used to get and error quickly rather than the 10 second delay.

Thanks in advance.
Gaurav

Comment: If there is a 10s delay with one JAVA version and 0.6s delay with another JAVA version, the problem probably lies within the JAVA version and not Oracle database settings.